# what are the code completetion systems available for emacs core (23.3 or 24)?

Tags: emacs

I use `auto-completion` mode which is not inbuilt. good but not the best IMO. So I was wondering is there inbuilt generic plugins for completion in emacs like you see in IDEs.

to name,
`dabbrev`
`hippie expansion`

I think these two are different from `auto-completion` mode kind which I am looking for.

EDIT:
I like to extend one of any completion system to support a scripting language which I use regularly for scientific data visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is CEDET package in GNU Emacs starting from version 23, but it slightly outdated, and it's better to use CEDET from its repository. I have [an article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) on setting and use CEDET from repository.

Why don't you want to use external packages? With new packaging system in GNU Emacs (package.el) and with things, like [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get), it's very easy to install new packages into GNU Emacs...

Comment: thanks for the reply. what are the languages CEDET will support. is it easy to extend?. please see my edit of the Question.

Comment: look into official documentation on how to add support for new language - http://cedet.sourceforge.net/addlang.shtml

Answer (score 1):

CEDET's autocompletion is the only drop-down completion package provided in core Emacs. The core in-place completion packages are `hippie-expand` and `dabbrev`.

The primary non-core packages which provide drop-down completion are `auto-complete` and [company](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs/CompanyMode); the former appears to be the most popular these days.

There's also [anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs/Anything), which is an interactive completion package. While it doesn't provide drop-down completion at the cursor position, the way it works is really rather nice, so it's worth investigating.

With a bit of tweaking, `dabbrev` and `hippie-expand` can be a lot more effective than you might expect, but if you want something more visual and interactive, my advice is to look beyond the core packages and go for `auto-complete` or perhaps `anything`.

(For what it's worth, I use both `hippie-expand` and `auto-complete` myself.)

Comment: @steve. thanks for the reply. Infact your emacs.d repo helped me to start enjoy emacs experience. Special thanks to you. I am using auto-complete right now, wanted to extend(please see my edit) that for the language I use. So asked this question to select the suitable/best choice. I will check out anything

Answer (score 0):

As a C programmer I tried http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense.
I read an interview where the CEDET author said that this is actually better because it hooks directly into gcc. However its quite a hassle to install gccsense because I had to compile a modified gcc. Once this package is included in distributions I would use it.

Comment: there is rudimentary support for code completion using clang/LLVM in the fresh CEDET...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try out predictive mode.  While not exactly a code completion package, it comes close to it by predicting your frequently used words, which in a coding platform is definitely a limited vocabulary.

http://www.dr-qubit.org/emacs.php

The emacs wiki has a good explanation too.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode